# How to create a sticky navbar on scroll in react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-hooks, nav

I'm trying to add the sticky navbar effect to the navbar of a site when a user scrolls down. i.e I want the navbar to become fixed at the top of the page when the browser is scrolled down a certain height

I'm trying to implement this with react hooks. Here's the code for the navbar

**Navbar.js**

```js
   import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

    const NavBar = () => {
    // sticky nav
    const [stickyClass, setStickyClass] = useState("");

    function stickNavbar() {
        let windowHeight = window.scrollY;
        setStickyClass("sticky-nav") ? windowHeight > 500 : setStickyClass("");
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener("scroll", stickNavbar);
    }, []);

return (
        <nav className="relative w-full p-4">
            <div className={`flex w-full flex-row items-center justify-between ${stickyClass}`}>
             navbar content goes here ....
            <div/>
<nav/>
```

I'm using tailwindcss for styling so there's no external stylesheet, however the `sticky-nav` class applies some of tailwindcss's utility classes.

**components.css**

```css
/* Navbar */
.sticky-nav {
    @apply fixed top-0 left-0 w-full shadow-md z-20;
}
```

I did research it online but nothing really helpful came up, really hoping anyone could help me out here :) .

Answer (score 7):

Try this :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function Navbar() {
  const [stickyClass, setStickyClass] = useState('relative');

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', stickNavbar);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', stickNavbar);
    };
  }, []);

  const stickNavbar = () => {
    if (window !== undefined) {
      let windowHeight = window.scrollY;
      windowHeight > 500 ? setStickyClass('fixed top-0 left-0 z-50') : setStickyClass('relative');
    }
  };

  return <div className={`h-16 w-full bg-gray-200 ${stickyClass}`}>Navbar</div>;
}
```

**Demo (without Tailwinds but same result):** [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vyxj8t)

Comment: Demo is not working on Safari

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find a implementation of it in the most simplest way without using any external libraries or bootstrap. It even works **with dynamic size** of the navbar itself. This implementation uses a JSX file and a css file which is saved in the same directory under following name: `navbar.module.css`.

The styling provided in this file is:

```css
/* Only for setting up the element */
.navbarOffset {
  padding: 10em;
}

/* Only for styling */
.content {
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 0.25em 1em 0.25em 1em;
}

/* Fix the navbar to the screen to create the sticky effect */
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
}
```

You may will come into trouble where the navbar is "behind" the scrollbar. The reason for this is that you need to define `box-sizing: border-box;` in order to work as intended.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";

// Import the stylesheets
import styles from 'navbar.module.css'


const StickyNavbar = () => {
  // All states
  const [sticky, setSticky] = useState(false);
  const [navHeight, setNavHeight] = useState(0);

  // All refs
  const navbar = useRef();
  const navbarOffset = useRef();

  // Mount the Event Listener on loading the site
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = () => {

      // Get the offset to the top
      const value = navbarOffset.current.clientHeight;

      // Set the boolean value 
      setSticky(window.pageYOffset >= value);
    }
  
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);

    // Set the height of the Navbar
    setNavHeight(navbar.current.clientHeight);

    // Remove the listener when cleaning up
    return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
  }, []);

 
  return (
    <>
      <div ref={navbarOffset}>This is the element before!</div>
      {/* Always add the content class and only if it is sticky the other class */}
      <div ref={navbar} className={`${styles.content} ${sticky && styles.sticky}`}>
        I'm the content of the Navbar
      </div>
      {/* To prevent the next content to "jump" behind the navbar */}
      <div style={sticky ? ({ marginTop: navHeight }) : ({})}></div>
    </>
  )
}

export default StickyNavbar;
```

I hope this can help you! For more questions I'm free to ask!